# SQLAlchemy DataError closes transaction

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I have a model with a `UUID` type primary key.  Users can query the model by its ID.  If a user inputs a non-uuid type id, I want to be able to catch the error and marshal my own message.  However, DataErrors close the transaction and prevent me from validating all of the remaining ids.

How can I reopen the transaction or prevent it from closing?

Code:

```
try:
    some_model.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
except DataError:
    errors.append('failed :(')

other_model.query.filter_by(id=valid_uuid).first() # InternalError - Would work if it came first.
```

Error:

```
InternalError: (InternalError) current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

Comment: You can't. You should validate your input before sending it to your RDBMS.

Comment: @univerio Okay thank you.  I assumed as much so I removed my implementation.  Using sqlalchemy-utils UUIDType fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation of the `UUID` primary key column was poor.  I removed my implementation and instead chose to use the `sqlalchemy-utils` package.  The `UUIDType` column was a drop in replacement and removed the `DataError`s.